# external JS file is not loading

Tags: javascript

The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to link an external javascript file to my main HTML program but I can't seem to make it happen.

Here is the validation I have in javascript.

```
function validateFirstName () { //test input for 2-20 characters allowed
    var fName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var rel = /^[a-zA-Z\s\'\-]{2,20}$/;
    
    if (rel.test(fName)){//if input is valid, update page to show succesful entry
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "green";
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "valid";
    return true;
    }
    else {//if input is invalid, update page to prompt for new input
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").style.color = "Red";
        document.getElementById("firstNamePrompt").innerHTML = "<strong>Enter 2-20 characters!</strong>;
    return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Together2.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="formvalidation10.js"></script>
        <title>Sign Up</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <div id="fullpage">
                <h1>SIGN UP WITH US</h1>
                <BR/>
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"/>
                <BR/>
                <BR/>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label_col">First Name:</td>
                        <td class="input_col"><input name="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" onblur="validateFirstName();"></td>
                        <td class="feedback_col"><span id="firstNamePrompt">&nbsp;</span></td>
                        
                    </tr>
```

I've looked to similar answers but I still can't find the problem. Could you please check it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you opening the .html file directly in your browser? Or are you hosting the files with a webserver such as Apache or nginx? Are the files in the same directory?

Comment: There is a missing `"` at the end of your "Enter 2-20 characters!" string.

Comment: Learn to use your developer tools in your browser. And get a decent IDE which would have highlighted the error.

Comment: @Ivar that was it! I was looking for the error almost 2 days now. I'm new in this so I don't have a lot of experience with the developer tools in the browser. I need a lot more practice, Thank you for the help!